# Is it possible to get Performance Counter in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, azure, perfmon

Is it possible to read PerfMon counters in Azure Websites / Azure Worker roles / Windows VMs like it can be done in an local console application?

```
PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
perfCounter.CategoryName = "Memory";
perfCounter.CounterName = "Available MBytes";
float result = perfCounter.NextValue();
```

I know about Azure Diagnostics, but I don't want to store these values in the table stoarge. I just want to directly read them and send them somewhere immediately.

**edit** for 1. comment: On Azure Websites I get an Exception "Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied" which I think is because of the shared ressources the website is running on.
At the moment I can't test worker/web roles but everthing I found regarding PerfMon Counters on those roles has to do with Azure Diagnostics which made me think there could be a restriction on those roles too like there is one at azure websites.

Comment: Yes, the same code should work fine.  Have you tried it and are you getting an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access performance counter programmatically in Microsoft Azure web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632001/access-performance-counter-programmatically-in-microsoft-azure-web-app)