# Access performance counter programmatically in Microsoft Azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to access CPU, RAM and ASP.NET requests performance counter from web app via some API?
When I call it using `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue` method I get exception:

```
Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
```

I have seen examples with Web Roles, but nothing about websites.

Comment: Your application will not have permissions to-do this. I am sure other methods such as WMI will also have issues.

Comment: Another way of getting this information is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352297/can-an-azure-web-site-app-determine-its-instances-cpu-memory-usage/29426076#29426076

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-and-azure-websites.aspx) it is not supported on Azure Websites:

> Windows Performance counter collection isn’t supported on an Azure WebSite

You can however monitor the CPU usuage and Memory Working set using the Monitor tab in the old management portal or directly on the website "blade" using the new portal. Maybe you can get these data out programatically using [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites)

Comment: Thanks, I will also repost answer of Byron Tardif  from another source here:
Access to machine perf counters are blocked by the multitenant nature of the service. We are working on exposing the same metrics you can see in the portal through our SDK, this way you will be able to query for CPU,RAM, etc at the App Service Plan level as well as individual instances, you should be able to access site metrics the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to permission issue here is the solution for that.
Step 1: Just add an app.manifest file into particular solution
step 2: add the following tag into manifest file.

> < requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

Step 3: Finish.